# How to sort a D3 clustered chart by a no displayed column

Tags: d3.js

I am creating a clustered chart in D3 which shows a number of volume types split by Brand.  The data also includes an image per brand and a sortID.

I'm able to render the chart ok along with the images but what I'm trying to do now is sort the chart by the 'sortID' column.  Not too sure how to do this given that i've excluded the column from the refined dataset:

```
    var data2 = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
  return key !== "brand_alt" & key !== "brand_image" & key !== "sortID"
});
```

Is there anyway I can still sort the chart using 'sortID' or would I need to redesign?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/Ld937oc5/70/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply sort before you exclude the column. That is, before defining the `data2` in your question, add the following:

```
data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.sortID, b.sortID))
```

Full example:

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 70,
    left: 40
  },
  // width = pbi.width - margin.left - margin.right,
  //height = pbi.height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  imagesize = 35;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#F8B90B", "#8F1F61", "#2B328C", "#C1D42F", "#5AB88D", "#00A5D3", "#2B328C"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x0)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
  "brand_alt": "A",
  "Brand": 2704659,
  "Facility": 4499890,
  "Location": 2159981,
  "Market": 3853788,
  "Merchandising": 10604510,
  "Price": 8819342,
  "Operations": 4114496,
  "sortID": 4,
  "brand_image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/LEGO_logo.svg/512px-LEGO_logo.svg.png"
}, {
  "brand_alt": "B",
  "Brand": 2027307,
  "Facility": 3277946,
  "Location": 1420518,
  "Market": 2454721,
  "Merchandising": 7017731,
  "Price": 5656528,
  "Operations": 2472223,
  "sortID": 6,
  "brand_image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/LEGO_logo.svg/512px-LEGO_logo.svg.png"
}, {
  "brand_alt": "C",
  "Brand": 1208495,
  "Facility": 2141490,
  "Location": 1058031,
  "Market": 1999120,
  "Merchandising": 5355235,
  "Price": 5120254,
  "Operations": 2607672,
  "sortID": 5,
  "brand_image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/LEGO_logo.svg/512px-LEGO_logo.svg.png"
}, {
  "brand_alt": "D",
  "Brand": 1140516,
  "Facility": 1938695,
  "Location": 925060,
  "Market": 1607297,
  "Merchandising": 4782119,
  "Price": 4746856,
  "Operations": 3187797,
  "sortID": 1,
  "brand_image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/LEGO_logo.svg/512px-LEGO_logo.svg.png"
}, {
  "brand_alt": "E",
  "Brand": 894368,
  "Facility": 1558919,
  "Location": 725973,
  "Market": 1311479,
  "Merchandising": 3596343,
  "Price": 3239173,
  "Operations": 1575308,
  "sortID": 5,
  "brand_image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/LEGO_logo.svg/512px-LEGO_logo.svg.png"
}, {
  "brand_alt": "F",
  "Brand": 737462,
  "Facility": 1345341,
  "Location": 679201,
  "Market": 1203944,
  "Merchandising": 3157759,
  "Price": 3414001,
  "Operations": 1910571,
  "sortID": 2,
  "brand_image": "https://planning-int.kalibrate.com/planningimages/305/logos/7-Eleven.svg"
}];

data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.sortID, b.sortID))
var data2 = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
  return key !== "brand_alt" & key !== "brand_image" & key !== "sortID"
});

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.volumes = data2.map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      value: +d[name]
    };
  });
});

x0.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.brand_alt;
}));
x1.domain(data2).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d3.max(d.volumes, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });
})]);


svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)


var xxx = svg.selectAll(".xxx")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.brand_alt) + ",0)";
  });

xxx.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.volumes;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.name);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand() * 0.9)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.name);
  });

/*
  xxx.selectAll("text")
.data(function(d) {
    return d.volumes;
  })
  .enter().append("text")
  
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.name) + x1.rangeBand() / 2;
  })
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value) - 8
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return (d.value) 
  })

*/


  //image

svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("images")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("svg:image")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return (x0(d.brand_alt) + x0.rangeBand() / 2) - 18
  })
  .attr("y", height + margin.bottom - 40)
  .attr("width", imagesize)
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.brand_image });



var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(data2.slice())
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.8/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='chart'>

</div>
```